# Can I run Android apps from Windows?

Tags: apps, android

Does Windows Phone have something to help use Android apps, similar to the way Wine helps us use Windows software on Linux? I'm curious whether or not such an app exists for Windows phone. I've created a table to help illustrate what I mean:

| Operating system of device | Operating system of software | Compatibility app |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Linux | Windows | Wine |
| Windows Phone | Android | ? |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone does not have any such functionality. There was always rumor and talk and even plans to make it happen (search "Project Astoria"), but Microsoft backed off. They only recently added the ability to use [Android Apps in Windows 11](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/10/20/introducing-android-apps-on-windows-11-to-windows-insiders/), but that feature will, sadly, never be coming to Windows Phone in any official capacity.

There was a way, with very specific models of device and builds of Windows Phone, that you could [hack Android support in to some devices](https://windowsunited.de/so-koennt-ihr-jede-beliebige-android-app-auf-eurem-windows-phone-nutzen/), but these days even the tools you would need **just to attempt it** are no longer available for download.

Comment: +25. You now have the privilage to upvote questions!